# Change the color of SVG with external source via jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, svg

I have 3 SVGs shown below. I can only change the color of the inline SVG. Any ideas why? (Code hosted on IIS)

```html
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <object id="objectSvg" type="image/svg+xml" data="eq.svg"></object>
        <svg id="svg" width="100" height="100" viewBox="0 0 300 300">
            <use xlink:href="eq.svg#EarthquakeSymbol"></use>
        </svg>

        <svg id="inline" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" preserveAspectRatio="none" x="0px" y="0px" width="300px" height="300px">
            <circle cx="150" cy="150" r="140" stroke="black" stroke-width="20" fill="none"/>
            <path id="mypath"stroke="#000000" stroke-width="20" stroke-linejoin="miter" stroke-linecap="butt" stroke-miterlimit="3" fill="none" d="M 35.5 141.55 L 81.05 141.55 108.75 86.1 150.35 223.05 189.4 132.8 207.95 172.5 222.7 141.65 265.8 141.65"/>
        </svg>
        <script>
            $('#objectSvg path').css({ stroke: "#ff0000" });
            $('#svg path').css({ stroke: "#ff0000" });
            $('#inlineSvg path').css({ stroke: "#ff0000" });</script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: which ones color you want to change?

Comment: Missing opening `<head>` tag

Comment: try this http://jsfiddle.net/kishoresahas/fbw536ks/1

Comment: add a filter to recolor images - one of the things filters are useful for - tool of last resort

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am pretty sure you can't style externally loaded SVGs with css. Why not cut and paste the code from the external SVG into your html like the other two you have?

This is a great resource for information about using SVGs: https://css-tricks.com/using-svg/

Comment: This link was one the places I got most of the info.

Comment: You can style them with CSS if you inject the CSS into the loaded document with javascript.